# Why is my JS game not displaying in a canvas in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to recreate this game https://codeguppy.com/run.html?mars_attack/program
the exact game locally on my computer in vs code. But I'm having trouble.
I have made these files for it but nothing seems to display on the website.

[![Files][1]][1]

Here is how the current site looks like:
[![current site][2]][2]

Here is my HTML code:

```
 <body>
<canvas class="canvas"></canvas>

<script src="intro.js" async defer></script>
<script src="mountains.js" async defer></script>
<script src="ship.js" async defer></script>
<script src="stars.js" async defer></script>
<script src="game.js" async defer></script>
<script src="enemy.js" async defer></script>
```

Here is the code for intro.js:

```
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = 640;
canvas.height = 480;

let stars = createStars();
let flashState = true;

function loop() {
    clear();
    update();
    draw();
}

function update() {
    if (frameCount % 20 === 0) flashState = !flashState;

    // Update stars
    for (let star of stars) {
        star.x--;
        if (star.x < 0) star.x = canvas.width;
    }
}

function createStars() {
    let stars = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        stars.push({
            x: random(canvas.width),
            y: random(canvas.height)
        });
    }

    return stars;
}

function clear() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function draw() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "Black";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    ctx.textAlign = "center";

    ctx.fillStyle = "White";
    ctx.font = "60px Arial";
    ctx.fillText("Mars Attack", canvas.width / 2, 100);

    ctx.font = "20px Arial";
    ctx.fillText("1 - Easy Mode", canvas.width / 2, 200);
    ctx.fillText("2 - Expert Mode", canvas.width / 2, 270);

    ctx.fillStyle = "LightGray";
    ctx.font = "14px Arial";
    ctx.fillText("Mountains are just decor", canvas.width / 2, 220);
    ctx.fillText("Mountains are obstacles", canvas.width / 2, 290);

    if (flashState) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "White";
        ctx.font = "20px Arial";
        ctx.fillText("Press key 1 or 2 to start game", canvas.width / 2, 350);
    }

    // Draw stars
    ctx.fillStyle = "White";
    for (let star of stars) {
        ctx.fillRect(star.x, star.y, 1, 1);
    }

    ctx.fillStyle = "Maroon";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(250, 500);
    ctx.lineTo(0, canvas.height);
    ctx.lineTo(500, canvas.height);
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(500, 400);
    ctx.lineTo(300, canvas.height);
    ctx.lineTo(700, canvas.height);
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(750, 300);
    ctx.lineTo(500, canvas.height);
    ctx.lineTo(1000, canvas.height);
    ctx.fill();
}

function keyPressed(key) {
    if (key === "1" || key === "2") showScene("Game", key);
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    if (event.key === '1' || event.key === '2') {
        keyPressed(event.key);
    }
});

setInterval(loop, 1000 / 60); // Call loop() 60 times per second
```

Could someone please help me? if you need code from the other files just ask.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCiY8.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJeNN.png

Answer (score 0):

There are some stuff missing in your code.
I assume you have given only a part of your html code here.

In **intro.js**, you have not initialized the canvas variable

```
const canvas = document.querySelector('.canvas');
```

You have also used a frameCount variable without declaration

```
const frameCount = 60;
```

And in createStars() function, the code to create random number is

```
x: Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width),
y: Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.height)
```

This will give you some output, but it's glitchy on my side...

Note: btw, all of these errors are given in the console, so whenever something goes wrong, it's gonna be useful to check the console

Comment: Still nothing is displaying after implementing those fixes, should I send the code for my other files too since console is showing errors for those files?

Comment: It has displayed for me with just those two files after the fix, but sure... (Be sure to check that the html document is complete)

Comment: No like my game isn't displaying, the canvas is displaying fine but the game stuff isn't